# Iterating over list of str to make a str with spaces

Tags: python, string, list

i have:

```
letters = ['h','e','l','l','o']
```

and i need:

```
'h e l l o'
```

so I've tried using a for loop as follows:

```
new_str = ''
for str in letters:
    new_str += str + ' '
```

however, the result is:

```
new_str = 'h e l l o '
```

is there a way to do this without the empty string after the o? as in without doing something after i already get the result.

Sorry i forgot to mention if there's a way to do this by iterating over the list.

Comment: You have to stop changing your question.  It is confusing people. Anyways, what do you mean by "iterating over the list"?  Do you mean you have to use a for-loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> letters = ['h','e','l','l','o']

>>> mystr = ' '.join(letters)

>>> print mystr

'h e l l o'
```

That's the simplest, cleanest way, but
if you must use a for loop for some reason, you could do the following:

```
mystr = ''
# this keeps the whole operation within the for loop
for i in range(len(letters)):
    mystr += letters[i] + ' '
    if i == len(letters)-1: # this condition will be tested each iteration, but it seemed more in keeping with your question
        mystr = mystr[:-1]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> letters = ['h','e','l','l','o']
>>> " ".join(letters)
'h e l l o'
>>>
```

---

**Edit:**

I think you are saying that you must use a for-loop.  If so, you can use this:

```
>>> letters = ['h','e','l','l','o']
>>> mystr = ""
>>> for letter in letters:
...     mystr += letter + " "
...
>>> mystr.strip()
'h e l l o'
```

Note however that, if your list contains spaces, you should use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) at the end instead of  [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
>>> mystr[:-1]
'h e l l o'
>>>
```

That way, you don't remove any spaces on the ends that were supposed to be there.

Comment: Why capitalize? Doesnt seem to be part of OP's question.

Comment: why is .upper happening up in here?

Comment: For both of you, the OP changed his question.  His original one said he wanted the letters to be uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
string = ""
for letter in "hello":
    string += letter + " "

string = string[:-1]
```

That last line simply removes the trailing whitespace. Read up on slicing [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). Alternatively use `string = string.strip()` which always removes the trailing space in the general case.

If you don't necessarily have to use an explicit loop I'd recommend going with `str.join()` as demonstrated in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Something different, but still not as elegant as simple str.join

```
>>> print ''.join(reduce(lambda a, b: a + ' ' + b, letters))
```